# Python program that opens thousands of TCP connections to a server

Tags: python, linux, sockets, centos

I need to write a python program that opens thousands of persistent connections to a server farm which sits behind a LoadBalancer. Env is: VirtualBox based CentOS 8.4.2105 VM with 4 VCPU's and 12GB of RAM.

I wrote a program in python (I'm not a real developer) and I noticed this:

1. If I run the program with user1, I can open Max 32,665 connections
2. If I run 2 copies of the program with user 1, I can open Max 36,416 connections
3. I ran 2 copies of the program, one with user1 and other with user2. In this case I was able to open Max 45,549 connections.
4. I bumped /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max to 120000 and now I repeated 3) above and I can open 64,512 connections

My goal is to open like 120K connections to the LB from a single VM. The VM has multiple interfaces.

So basically the questions that I have are:

1. How can I have 60K or more connections with a single user?
2. Is there a better way to write my program so that I do not need a thread per connection so that I do not hit these Max Thread's limits?

The program is like this:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as PoolExecutor
import http.client
import socket
import ssl
import time
import json
hostname = 'lb01'
port = 80
eco='{"id":"echo","method":"echo","params":[]}'

def get_it(ids):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((hostname,port))
  
    # message you send to server
    message = "a"
    while True:
  
        # message sent to server
        #s.send(message.encode('ascii'))
  
        # messaga received from server
        #data = s.recv(1024)
        while (1):
            time.sleep(60)
            #ssock.send(eco.encode())
  
ids=[]
for counter in range(100000,130000): 
   id=str(counter)
   print (id)
   ids.append(id)
print(ids)
with PoolExecutor(max_workers=30000) as executor:
    for _ in executor.map(get_it, ids):
        pass
```

This is the output of ulimit -a:

```
[root@driver02 ~]# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 46964
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1000000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1000000
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
[root@driver02 ~]#
```

At the bottom of  /etc/sysctl.conf  I added

```
fs.file-max = 2097152
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535

At the bottom of  /etc/security/limits.conf I addedL
* soft nproc 1000000
* hard nproc 1000000
* soft nofile 1000000
* hard nofile 1000000
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: every connection needs separated port but TCP can use max 65 535 (2^16) ports. And system uses also many port to communicate with other programs  ans services so you can't use 65 535 only for your program.

Comment: I plan to update the program to bind to different IP's. The questions that I really have  are: what to tune to get single instance/user and if I can update program to use less treads